# How can we pass boolean state in an other view in SwiftUi

Tags: swift, swiftui, state

I have to different structs in one. I have one checkbox(selectAll) in main view and other checkboxes in another view. When I click select all it works fine and all are selected but if I uncheck any of the below list the selectAll checkbox remains selected. selectAll is a boolean state. I want to uncheck that.
The function on the list toggle is another class not in a selectAll class.
Thanks
Any help would be appreciated.

this is checkbox list code

```
  Button(action: {
                print("to action")
                                   self.packDto.selected.toggle()
                
                                   if self.packDto.selected {
                                       self.selectedPacks.selectedPackIdList.append(self.packDto.id)
                                       //                        self.selectedPacks.selectedPackIdList.append(1)
                                   } else {
                                       if self.selectedPacks.selectedPackIdList.contains(self.packDto.id) {
                                           self.selectedPacks.selectedPackIdList.remove(at: self.selectedPacks.selectedPackIdList.firstIndex(of: self.packDto.id)!)
                                       } }
                                   
                                   self.selectedPacks.objectWillChange.send()
                                   self.selectedCount += (self.packDto.selected ? 1 : -1)
                                   self.parentObservablePublisher.send()
                                   print(String(self.selectedPacks.selectedPackIdList.count)
                           
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: (self.packDto.customsDeclarationId == nil || self.customsDeclarationId == self.packDto.customsDeclarationId) && self.selectableStatusId.contains(packDto.statusId) ?
                    (packDto.selected ? "checkmark.rectangle.fill" : "rectangle")
                    : "slash.circle").resizable().scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                    .padding(.top, 2)
                    .padding(.bottom, 2)
    })
This is main view code where select all is being called
    func selectAllPackets() {
        self.selectAll.toggle()
        for (index, dto) in self.packListViewModel.packDtoList.enumerated() {
            // TODO selectable pack status id
            if (dto.statusId == PackStatusEnum.WAITING_LOGISTIC.rawValue )  && dto.selected != self.selectAll {
                dto.selected = self.selectAll
                selectedCount += (self.selectAll ? 1 : -1)
                print("In maın",selectedCount)
                self.packListViewModel.packDtoList[index] = dto.copy() as! PackDtoprint(self.selectAll)}}  self.packListViewModel.objectWillChange.send()}
```

Comment: Would you add your code that demo a problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please [edit] your question to include a [example] showing what you have already tried. See also [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

So the selectAll toggle will enable/ disable all child toggles.

```
struct ParentView: View {
    @State var selectAll = false
    @State var selectOne = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle("Select all", isOn: $selectAll).onChange(of: selectAll) { value in
                selectOne = selectAll
            }
            
            ChildView(selectAll: $selectAll, selectOne: $selectOne)
        }
    }
}
    
struct ChildView: View {
    @Binding var selectAll: Bool
    @Binding var selectOne: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        Toggle("Select one", isOn: $selectOne).onChange(of: selectOne) { value in
            if !selectOne {
                selectAll = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I used this but for that, I had to describe the new childview because I was using the same view in order to display.

Comment: If it helped you solve the issue don't forget to mark it as an answer.